# Faster Alternative to std::ofstream

Tags: c++, std, fstream, ofstream

I generate a set of data files. As the files are supposed to be readable, they **text files** (opposed to binary files).

To output information to my files, I used very comfortable **std::ofstream** object.

In the beginning, when the data to be exported was smaller, the time needed to write to the files was not noticeable. However, as the information to be exported has accumulated, it takes now **around 5 minutes** to generate them.

As I started being **bothered by waiting**, my question is obvious: **Is there any faster alternative to std::ofstream**, please? In case there is faster alternative, will it be worth of rewritting my application? In other words, **could the time saved be +50%**? Thank you.

---

### Update:

I was asked to show you **my code** that generates the above files, so here you are - **the most time consuming loop**:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open(strngCollectiveSourceFileName,ios::out);

fout << "#include \"StdAfx.h\"" << endl;
fout << "#include \"Debug.h\"" << endl;
fout << "#include \"glm.hpp\"" << endl;
fout << "#include \"" << strngCollectiveHeaderFileName.substr( strngCollectiveHeaderFileName.rfind(TEXT("\\")) + 1) << "\"" << endl << endl;

fout << "using namespace glm;" << endl << endl << endl;


for (unsigned int nSprite = 0; nSprite < vpTilesetSprites.size(); nSprite++ )
{
    for(unsigned int nFrameSet = 0; nFrameSet < vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets.size(); nFrameSet++)
    {

        // display index definition
        fout << "// Index Definition: " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetLongDescription() << "\n";
        string strngIndexSignature = strngIndexDefinitionSignature;
        strngIndexSignature.replace(strngIndexSignature.find(TEXT("#aIndexArrayName#")), strlen(TEXT("#aIndexArrayName#")), TEXT("a") + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->GetObjectName() + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetFrameSetName() + TEXT("IndexData") );
        strngIndexSignature.replace(strngIndexSignature.find(TEXT("#ClassName#")), strlen(TEXT("#ClassName#")), strngCollectiveArrayClassName );        
        fout << strngIndexSignature << "[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};\t\t" << "// " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetShortDescription() << ": Index Definition\n\n";


        // display vertex definition
        fout << "// Vertex Definition: " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetLongDescription() << "\n";

        string strngVertexSignature = strngVertexDefinitionSignature;
        strngVertexSignature.replace(strngVertexSignature.find(TEXT("#aVertexArrayName#")), strlen(TEXT("#aVertexArrayName#")), TEXT("a") + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->GetObjectName() + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetFrameSetName() + TEXT("VertexData") );
        strngVertexSignature.replace(strngVertexSignature.find(TEXT("#ClassName#")), strlen(TEXT("#ClassName#")), strngCollectiveArrayClassName );
        fout << strngVertexSignature << "[" << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetFramesCount() << "] =\n";
        fout << "{\n";

        for (int nFrameNo = 0; nFrameNo < vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetFramesCount(); nFrameNo++)
        {
            fout << "\t" << "{{ vec4(" << fixed << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[0].vPosition.fx << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[0].vPosition.fy << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[0].vPosition.fz << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[0].vPosition.fw << "f), vec2(" << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[0].vTextureUV.fu << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[0].vTextureUV.fv << "f) },  // " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetShortDescription() << " vertex 1: vec4(x, y, z, w), vec2(u, v) \n";
            fout << "\t" << " { vec4(" << fixed << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[1].vPosition.fx << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[1].vPosition.fy << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[1].vPosition.fz << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[1].vPosition.fw << "f), vec2(" << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[1].vTextureUV.fu << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[1].vTextureUV.fv << "f) },  // " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetShortDescription() << " vertex 2: vec4(x, y, z, w), vec2(u, v) \n";
            fout << "\t" << " { vec4(" << fixed << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[2].vPosition.fx << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[2].vPosition.fy << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[2].vPosition.fz << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[2].vPosition.fw << "f), vec2(" << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[2].vTextureUV.fu << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[2].vTextureUV.fv << "f) },  // " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetShortDescription() << " vertex 3: vec4(x, y, z, w), vec2(u, v) \n";
            fout << "\t" << " { vec4(" << fixed << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[3].vPosition.fx << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[3].vPosition.fy << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[3].vPosition.fz << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[3].vPosition.fw << "f), vec2(" << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[3].vTextureUV.fu << "f, " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->vpFrames[nFrameNo]->aVertices[3].vTextureUV.fv << "f) }},  // " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetShortDescription() << " vertex 4: vec4(x, y, z, w), vec2(u, v) \n\n";
        }
        fout << "};\n\n\n\n";
    }
}

fout.close();
```

Comment: In my experience, the problem is rarely with the specific IO interface used, but much more frequently, the problem is with building _strings_ via concatenation: `s1 += "foo"; s1 += "bar"; s1 += "baz"; print(s1);`. Show us your code, and don't jump to the conclusion that the _output_ is the problem. At least not without good profiling data to back it up... :)

Comment: @sarnold: +1, hi and thank you for your comment. Despite I use the above mentioned concatenations frequently, at this time, i do not think it is my case. I did as you recommended, and posted above the code of my most consuming loop generating the largest file.

Comment: On a side note; that is some of the hardest to read code I have seen lately.  Line breaks and variables are your friend.

Comment: *"at this time, i do not think it is my case.*" - how do you know?  I don't see any profiling data in your question.

Comment: @Ed S.: Hi Ed, thanks for your critics. :-) I will work on making my code more readable. :-) Regarding your second point, I referred to sarnold's comment, where he claimed, that one of the causes is string concatenation. As you can see above, I do not concatentate strings there.

Comment: @Bunkai I'd say that this _is exactly_ your case. I can't help but mention that your string manipulation is very bulky, those small `strlen()` calls will actually build up, not to mention the amount of re-allocation done by `std::string` to match what you're instructing it to do.

Comment: what are these lines doing then? `TEXT("a") + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->GetObjectName() + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetFrameSetName() + TEXT("VertexData")`.  You also have a lot of calls to functions like `strlen` which may be problematic in a tight loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What serious alternatives exist for the IOStream library? (besides cstdio)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171360/what-serious-alternatives-exist-for-the-iostream-library-besides-cstdio)

Comment: @Ed S.: +1 and understood. I will take a look if there is a good way to avoid those lines. You had good idea to post some my code. Besides other things, I leared a lot about my writing style :-). Thank you for taking look at my code, and advising.

Comment: @Billy: thanks for informing about the other article. I already studied it. Anyways, I would like to keep this article open, to let people refer directly to the source code attached. This might help others to avoid doing similar mistakes. Source code example was not in the link you offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are `vpTilesetSprites` and `vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]` stored? Are they implemented with lists or arrays? There is a *lot* of indexed access to them, and if they are list-like structures, you'll spend a lot of extra time following needless pointers. Ed S.'s comment is right: giving the long indexed temporary variables and linebreaks could make it easier to read, and *maybe* faster, too:

```
fout << "// Index Definition: " << vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetLongDescription() << "\n";
string strngIndexSignature = strngIndexDefinitionSignature;
strngIndexSignature.replace(strngIndexSignature.find(TEXT("#aIndexArrayName#")), strlen(TEXT("#aIndexArrayName#")), TEXT("a") + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->GetObjectName() + vpTilesetSprites[nSprite]->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet]->GetFrameSetName() + TEXT("IndexData") );
strngIndexSignature.replace(strngIndexSignature.find(TEXT("#ClassName#")), strlen(TEXT("#ClassName#")), strngCollectiveArrayClassName );
```

vs

```
string idxsig = strngIndexDefinitionSignature;
sprite sp = vpTilesetSprites[nSprite];
frameset fs = sp->vpFrameSets[nFrameSet];

fout << "// Index Definition: " << fs->GetLongDescription() << "\n";
idxsig.replace(idxsig.find(TEXT("#aIndexArrayName#")), strlen(TEXT("#aIndexArrayName#")),
    TEXT("a") + sp->GetObjectName() + fs->getFrameSetName() + TEXT("IndexData"));
idxsig.replace(idxsig.find(TEXT("#ClassName#")), strlen(TEXT("#ClassName#")),
    strngCollectiveArrayClassName);
```

But, the much bigger problem is how you're using strings as templates; you're looking for a given text string (and computing the length of your *needle* string every single time you need it!) *over and over again*.

Consider this: You're performing the find and replace operations `nSprite` * `nFrameSet` times. Each time through, this loop:

- makes a copy of `strngIndexDefinitionSignature`
- creates *four* temporary string objects when concatenating static and dynamic strings
- compute `strlen(TEXT("#ClassName#"))`
- compute `strlen(TEXT("#aIndexArrayName#"))`
- find start point of both
- replace both texts with new texts

And that's just the first four lines of your loop.

Can you replace your `strngIndexDefinitionSignature` with a *format string*? I assume it currently looks like this:

```
"flubber #aIndexArrayName# { blubber } #ClassName# blorp"
```

If you re-write it like this:

```
"flubber a %s%sIndexData { blubber } %s blorp"
```

Then your two find and replace lines can be replaced with:

```
sprintf(out, index_def_sig, sp->GetObjectName(), fs->getFrameSetName(),
    strngCollectiveArrayClassName);
```

This would remove two `find()` operations, two `replace()` operations, creating and destroying four temporary string objects, a string duplicate that was promptly over-written with two `replace()` calls, and two `strlen()` operations that return the same result every time (but aren't actually needed anyway).

You can then output your string with `<<` as usual. Or, you can change `sprintf(3)` to `fprintf(3)`, and avoid even the temporary C string.

Comment: @sarnold: +1, hi again sarnold. Abolutely fabulous answer. Thank you for your willingness to analyze my code. This answer is beneficial for me to improve my proramming skills in general. To answer your **first question**: all the data are stored in `std::vector<>` containers including `vpTileSprites[]`. I like using **Hungarian notation**, and the prefix **vp** suggests, the object it is a vector of pointers. I will obey your recommendation, and use variables more, to increase code readability, although, to me, my code is perfectly readable, as it is. :-)

Comment: @sarnold: I understand what you say. Regarding your **second question**: a large number fo data I take from _.ini_ files, including `strngIndexDefinitionSignature`. I get the information with the usage of `DWORD WINAPI GetPrivateProfileString()`. So all I have is a char array. I am not aware that I could apply your advice into the text within _.ini_ files where it is formatted as follows: `Index Definition  = const unsigned short #ClassName#::#aIndexArrayName#`. If you have any good and practical advice, that would really help.

Comment: Alghough all of the advices are very good here, from my viewpoint, _this_ is the most detailed and valuable answer. Threfore, I wish to mark this answer as the _Acceptable Answer_ to my question.

Comment: @sarnold: for **clarification** what I do: I organize a set of custom files to be processed into directories. Every directory contains _.ini_ file with specification, how the content in the particluar directory is supposed to be processed. **My application then takes both the _.ini_ files information and the contained files.** It processes them, plus, it otuputs a lot of _.txt_ data files. My question was related to those _.txt_ files.

Comment: @Bunkai, excellent feedback all around, I'm glad to have you on Stack Overflow. :) [cplusplus claims constant time access by index](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), so that's alright. It might be _expensive_ constant-time, but at least it is constant. If I knew C++ better, I'd have known that. :) Are you in a position to change the format of your `ini` files? `Index Definition = const unsigned short %s::%s`. This fails if the order changes.

Comment: @Bunkai,  [Google's CTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548075/c-string-template-library) could provide name-based replacement. After skimming its source for a while, it feels a bit 'heavy' for this task, but because it isn't building and re-building string objects, it _might_ work out faster in the end.

Comment: @sarnold: thanks for the kind words above:-). Yes, it is my application, so I am in charge of chaning the format of my `.ini` files or improving the application in any way. If you say, that `Index Definition = const unsigned short %s::%s` would work with `sprintf()` then I could implement your proposed solution. I could have tried it on my own, but, I did not consider it as functional. Thanks again for your good quality advices.  When the time allows, I will take serious look at my code, and estimate the effort needed to modify my code according your advices.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use C file I/O then you can give a try to; [**FastFormat**](http://www.fastformat.org). Look at the comparison for more info.

Comment: +1, hi and thanks for your great tip. I went through the home page of FastFormat, and one of the key imporovements is increased speed by **100-900% over std::iostream**. However, as others have pointed out, the reason to slow speed in my case can be _elsewhere_, not in the usage of std::ofstream.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you do it in large enough chunks, calling write() directly might be faster; that said, it's more likely that your biggest bottleneck doesn't have anything directly to do with std::ofstream.  The most obvious thing is to make sure you aren't using std::endl (because flushing the stream frequently will kill performance).  Beyond that, I would suggest profiling your app to see where it's actually spending the time.

Comment: +1, hi servn, and thanks for your alternative solutions. This might be elementary question from me, but because, I have never done it, how is profiling performed? Is it by applying some king of specialized **profiling tools**, that will measure bottlenecks, or is it simple observation analysis, and finding out manually, what areas of code might be problematic?

Comment: A profiler is a specialized tool; on Mac, Shark or Instruments, on Linux, oprofile (or callgrind).  You can also use a debugger as a sort of profiler; just repeatedly break into the debugger manually, and see what the stack traces look like.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of `ostream` is probably not your actual issue; I suggest using a profiler to determine where your real bottlenecks are. If `ostream` turns out to be your actual problem, you can drop down to `<cstdio>` and use `fprintf(FILE*, const char*, ...)` for formatted output to a file handle.

Comment: +1, Hi Jon. Your advice is basically in agreement with some other advices, saying, that my problem with speed might be elsewhere. If I understand correctly, I should use a **software profiler**, to analyze my application. **Could you advice, a good profiler**, please?

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori: The answer that @sarnold gave covers your current situation, but for your future reference, `gprof` (the GNU profiler) is a good profiler to use with GCC.

Comment: Hi again, and thanks very much. I will take a look at `gprof`. It is great that this site offers the opportunity to get advices from the best programmers in the world :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer will depend on what sort of text you are generating, and how you are generating it. C++ streams can be slow, but that mostly is because they can also do a lot more for you, such as locale-dependent formatting, and so on.

You may find speed ups with streams by bypassing some of the formatting (eg. `ostream::write`), or by writing characters directly to a streambuf instead (`streambuf::sputn`). Sometimes increasing the buffer size on the relevant streambuf helps (via `streambuf::pubsetbuf`).

If this isn't good enough, you might want to try C-style stdio files, eg `fopen`, `fprintf`, etc. It takes a little while to get used to the way the text is formatted if you're not used to that method but the performance is usually pretty good.

For the absolute top performance you usually have to go to OS-specific routines. Sometimes the direct low-level file routines are significantly better than the C stdio, but sometimes not - for example, I've seen some people say WriteFile on Win32 is the fastest method on Windows, whereas some Google hits report it as being slower than stdio. Another approach might be a memory-mapped file, eg. `mmap` + `msync` - this essentially uses your system memory as the disk and writes the actual data to disk in large blocks, which is likely to be near optimal. However you run the risk of losing all the data if you incur a crash half way for some reason, which may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: +1, hi and thanks for your very good advices. You offered even more solutions, and you advised which should be the most optimal and fastes choice on Windows platform. Originally, I was looking exactly for information like this, until, somebody has suggested, that **my problem can be elsewhere**: in usage of time consuming operations in my loop, as **string replacing, searching, strlen()** etc..

Comment: Since stdio calls `WriteFile`, calling `WriteFile` directly is less overhead and thus faster when writing lots of data. However, stdio is "faster" with many small writes because of the buffering that defers OS calls.