# PHP's compilers StringBuilder in C++

Tags: c++

PHP compiler has awesome feature, that evry PHP coder should know. Usage of it like that

```
$var1 = 123;
$var2 = 321;
$var3 = array( "key" => "value", "key2" => 123);

$variable = "Var1 has $var1 value. Var2 has $var2 value. 
    And now array part: {$var3["key"]}.";
```

And now questions, when i explained to other people what "PHPs string builder":

is - how i should call it? Beacos that isnt really StringBuilder for me ( but maybe it is ? ).

Is there any build in Boost or C++ algorithms that could do that for me? I could do that with regex, and replace / append to alredy existing string. I could do that by myself, but why i make bycicle if there is tons of them?

p.s. Maybe there isnt tons of them, but there at least one that i know - PHP's.

Comment: Regex is supported by the current standard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2548075/560648 but it depends on what you're actually trying to do (which is not at all clear).

Comment: i want to know how its called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is called *string interpolation*.**

It's not a mystery, or a secret; there's [an entire section of the PHP manual dedicated to explaining it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

C has `printf` that does a very similar thing:

```
const unsigned int MAX_SIZE = 255;
char variable[MAX_SIZE];
snprintf(variable, MAX_SIZE-1, "Var1 has %d value. Var 2 has %d value.", var1, var2);
```

In C++ you don't really need string interpolation and may simply build up a string using a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Var1 has " << var1 << " value. Var 2 has " << var2 << " value.";

const std::string variable = ss.str();
```

For actual templating I like [ctemplate](https://code.google.com/p/ctemplate/).

Comment: thank you for answer. And yes , i was needed someting like that. But i cant use *print* beacos you cant manipulate order of them. And i dont know PHP site that much, and php itself. That is just what i remember from PHP actually :D